# How to write a Python program that gives the same output in every run?

Tags: python, random, set, random-seed

I have the following code

```
import random

random.seed(42)

mylist = set(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"]) 
tn = random.sample(mylist, 4)
print(tn)
```

So far I would have expected this to always print the same result. However, on every consecutive run it returns a different sequence of 4 letters. I later found that it is stable when removing `set` (which in this minimal example serves no purpose other than to trigger the problem).

Why would someone implement `set` in a way that it is not deterministic? I can imagine that its implementation may need (pseudo-)random numbers, but even then I'd have hoped that my program is still deterministic, even when using `set`. I also noticed that this is version-dependent:

Python versions:

- 2.7.12: stable
- 3.5.2: different output
- 3.6.12: different output

How can I use `set` and still get reproducible output? Sorting `mylist` with `sorted` before sampling works, but it's quite unintuitive that you have to sort a list that is sorted again after a (naively) null-operation.

Comment: The order of elements in sets is not specified, so they might have done this intentionally to mess up applications that depend on a specific order.

Comment: But `sorted()` gives you another list, so you're losing the set.

Comment: String *hashes* aren't fixed between runs.

Comment: If you need reproducibility, you really need to make less assumptions. This wouldn't have been stable either on 2.7.12 if you tried testing on different computers - hashing is different on 32-bit and 64-bit builds.

Comment: This was changed by PEP 456; the hash algorithms are intentionally not reproducible to shut down linear time hash table attacks. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0456/

Comment: @BillyONeal, that's an interesting aspect.

Answer (score 5):

Your expectation is intuitive, but it is not part of the language specs.

The hashing mechanism for `set` is not specified; the Python implementation has no requirement to reproduce the hash mapping -- or whatever mechanism is used.  It can depend on recent storage use, available locations, system time, or the phase of the moon.

If your personal definition of "works" requires a reproducible mapping, then you are responsible to supply your own mapping, or to use a language facility that supports such stability.  Sorting does *not* give you set stability; it replaces the set with a sorted list.